# Proove that if $ \mu(A \triangle B) = 0 $, then $B$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

The complete statement is as follows:

Let $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$ a complete measure space, $A\in \mathcal{A}$ and $B \in \mathcal{P}(X)$.Proove that if $ \mu(A \triangle B) = 0 $, then $B$ is measurable.

My proof is as follows:

We can write 
$$ A \triangle B = (A\cup B)\cap (A\cap B)^{c} = (A\cap B^{c}) \cup (B\cap A^c) $$
And we know that $  (B\cap A^c) \subseteq A \triangle B$ and  $A \cap B \subseteq A$.

now, since $A \triangle B$, $ A $ are measurable and $\mu$  is complete we know $\mu(B\cap A^c) $, $\mu(A\cap B)$ exist, and by additivity of $\mu$

$\begin{align}  \mu(B\cap A^c) + \mu(A\cap B) &= \mu((B\cap A^c) \cup(A\cap B)) \\
&=\mu(B\cap(A^c\cup A)) \\
&=\mu(B\cap X)\\
&=\mu(B)
\end{align} $

$\therefore B$ is measurable.

Is my reasoning correct?  or there is a mistake?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. May be you wanted to prove that $\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(E\cap B)+\mu^*(E\cap B^c)$, but if yes, why $\mu$ is generated by an exterior measure ?

Comment: And measurability of a set has nothing to do with the measure. It is a property of the set its self and not of the measure.

Comment: @quallenjäger: In case of "Caratheodory measurability" it does. But indeed, without more precision on $\mathcal A$, it doesn't. Anyway, we miss informations.

Comment: So, some hint to prove that $B$ is measurable?

Comment: And by completeness you only know $B\A$ is measurable. You can’t conclude $A \cap B$ is measurable as $A$ is not nullset (Assuming your Nullset “A triangle B”is measurable). But I mean it is then obvious that  A \cup B$$ is measurable and it can be easily shown that $A \cap B$ is measurable by taking the suitable complement. If you are not given “A triangle B” is measurable Nullset, I don’t see a way to do it without any additional information.